# Display Day name with time

Tags: asp.net, datetime

How to display day name with time for example `Monday 10:10`? for example `Response.Write(?)`

Comment: Use the `DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString` after the desired name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd hh:mm tt"));
```

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: Actually `Response.Write` is bad practice in ASP.NET better something like `lbDateTime.Text = "...";` but +1 for the correct way anyway (the `dddd` format).

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: because OP was expecting in this form. See question.

Comment: @Thomas fair enough, but still IMO it's good idea to point him out it's not good practice anymore in ASP.NET as it will put this on top of everything else resulting in invalid HTML. (Assuming it's in the code behind, not injected to the `.aspx` of course)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd HH:MM"););
```